# Send a value from PHP to Node JS for execution

Tags: php, node.js, apache, shell-exec

Hello everyone!

I have a file called start.php and in this file I have set the value of x to 5. I have another file called check.js

In my PHP file I use shell_exec to run check.js

My question is, what should I do to make check.js check the value of x which is in start.php

Is it possible to do it this way while using shell_exec? If not what should I do?

Best regards

Comment: can check js take parameters?

Comment: I haven't programmed it do. I need to know how to make it to take the parameters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pass `x` in arguments when calling `check.js`

Assuming you have `check.js` located in a folder like this `c:\apps\check.js` here is some code you can try:

***`start.php`***

```
<?php

$x = 5;

$output = shell_exec("node.exe c:\apps\check.js x=$x");

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
```

---

***`c:\apps\check.js`***

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

const data = querystring.parse( process.argv[2] || '' );

const x = data.x;

console.log(x);
```

---

Node.js code is using `querystring` module (https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html) for parsing `x`.

> Update (if you need to pass more than one value)

***`start.php`***

```
<?php

$x = 5;
$y = 7;

$output = shell_exec("node.exe c:\apps\check.js x=$x+y=$y");

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

?>
```

---

***`c:\apps\check.js`***

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

const data = querystring.parse( process.argv[2] || '', '+' );

console.log(data.x);
console.log(data.y);
```

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: That is great example.

Comment: THIS IS FANTASTIC!!!!!!!!!!!!
But there is one problem. When I try it on CMD it works. But when I run the PHP file, it shows me a white page. 
Why?
Thanks

Comment: Can you check if you have `node.exe` in your PATH? If not try to either add it or use full path to node.exe in PHP code.

Comment: I do have node.exe in my path.

Comment: OHHH. I found out why it doesn't work.
In this line $output = shell_exec("node.exe c:\apps\check.js x=$x+y=$y");
the symbol of " doesn't run the code. But when I put " like ' it works.